# Create a manual data validation list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to make a very simple **manual** dropdown list in a cell with the values `Yes` or `No`.

I do **not** want to select a range of possibilities for only 2 options. So I want to enter the possible values manually.

It is my understanding according to these articles ([link1](https://excel-bytes.com/five-ways-to-create-a-list-for-data-validation-in-excel/), [link2](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-drop-down-list/#2-By-Entering-Data-Manually)), that I can do so by going to a cell, going to `data` > `data validation`. Select `List` from the allow dropdown and then in the source field enter my dropdown entries manually (comma seperated).

However, if I do so, I get this:

[image]

So, I get only 1 option `Yes,No` instead of 2 options with `Yes` or `No`. What am I doing wrong? I tried seperating them with a comma and a space aswell. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In source, write this `Yes;No` instead of `Yes,No`

Comment: Cheers. Did this change then? Because those articles clearly state that I should seperate the values with a comma.

Comment: Idk to be honest, are you usually using `,` or `;` in formulas ? Depending on region some use `,` instead of `;`

Comment: That might explain things. I don't use formulas that often. Well, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

first:

Control panel--> Region-->Formats Tab-->Additional settings--> Numbers Tab-->List separator value change to: ,(comma) then ok.ok